# How to remove all containers in the docker (permession denied) "all container's is active"

Tags: docker, permission-denied

i am new use with docker, and I can't delete active containers, and I can't stop containers
using `docker rm -v -f $(docker ps -qa)` AND `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`  and continuos error: `Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: beef39...: permission denied` or `rror response from daemon: Could not kill running container 16c..., cannot remove - permission denied`

full container's
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBm7K.png)

Comment: Where is the Beef?
Also .. sounds like an authentication error ..

Answer (score 0):

*Answering as I understand the question,*

By looking at your error I think you don't have permission to run docker commands.

So,

1. Add user user account to that group

   - `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
2. Change the current real group ID

   - `sudo newgrp docker`

after that try to run your commands again.

Comment: `docker` group should already exist, `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` should be all that's needed.

Comment: oh yes :) ill change the answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem as follows!

execute: `sudo aa-remove-unknown`

and run standard docker commands to stop and then kill the container

he will clean the apparmor in linux, it's a bug with apparmor and blocks actions that shut down created dockers